# WP all import is not importing data to custom field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, wpallimport

I have text input field created with ACF and want to import value to it:

```
function add_manual_button() {
    $link = the_field('navod');

    echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-12 text-center text-lg-left">';
    echo '<a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank" class="btn-manual btn btn-outline-secondary text-uppercase text-decoration-none font-weight-bold" style="border-radius: 20px; padding: 4px 6px; border-width: 2px;">Montážny návod</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'add_manual_button', 30);
```

This is not working as expected. Href attribute returns home URL of website.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are assigning $link, you need to say

```
get_field('navod')
```

not

```
the_field('navod')
```

the_field() will echo out a fields value, while get_field() gets the value and allows you to assign it.

Also, another quick tip, you might find it easier to close your php tags and just write standard html instead of echoing everything on different lines